# onClickListener for Strings in Android?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have searched the web for a way to do this, but perhaps I'm not searching for the right thing. I have a ListView that serves as a live feed, essentially. In each feedEntry object of this ListView (ArrayList) the application displays words separated by a space as one String. Here's an example of what one ListView item (one feedEntry) would display:

```
Sahara Africa Ohio Libya
```

I would like to have it so that the user can click on each word and a PopupWindow will display (which will, in turn have separate links in it). I understand how to set up this PopupWindow, but how would I attach an onClickListener for each of these words? I'm not sure which code would be helpful to you, but here is my main Feed activity (Feed.java):

```
public class Feed extends Activity {
ListView liveFeed;
static ArrayAdapter<feedEntry> aa;

static ArrayList<feedEntry> entries = new ArrayList<feedEntry>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feed);

    liveFeed = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.liveFeed);

    int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<feedEntry>(this, layoutID, entries);
    liveFeed.setAdapter(aa);


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer time = new Timer();
    TimerTask refresh = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    feedEntry.refreshFeed();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    time.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresh, 0, 5000);
  }
}
```

Here is my feedEntry class (for each feedEntry item in the ListView):

```
public class feedEntry {
private static int line=1;//use later
private String keywords;
private JSONArray data;

public feedEntry(JSONArray obj){
    data = obj;
    keywords="";
    try{
        for (int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
            JSONArray tmp = (JSONArray)data.get(i);
            keywords += tmp.get(0)+" ";
        }

    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

public String toString(){
    return keywords;
}

public static void addNewEntry(feedEntry entry){
    Feed.entries.add(0, entry);
    Feed.aa.notifyDataSetChanged();//notify the array adapter that data has changed
}

//connects to and parses the feed
static public void refreshFeed(){
    try{
        String url = "http://192.17.254.11:8080/getdata?nextline="+line;
        line++;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String input = null;
        try {
            while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(input + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        String enter = sb.toString();
        if (!enter.equals("None")){
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(enter);
            feedEntry add = new feedEntry(jArray);
            addNewEntry(add);
        }

        in.close();

    } catch(MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Again, I am very sorry for all of the code. I just wanted to give out as much as possible that may be relevant. At this point, I'm sure that I will need to include these onClickListeners in my Feed.java, since that's the main activity, but I'm not sure how to put them on separate words within a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am skeptical that your UX will be very good. Phones are tiny. Users will have great difficulty accurately tapping on one work versus another with lots of words per row.

Second, I am skeptical that a `ListView` is the right answer. A `GridView` would be simpler, if you want rows and columns of words.

All that being said, you will have to extend `ArrayAdapter`, override `getView()`, create individual `TextView`s per word, and set up `OnClickListeners` for each `TextView`.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare. I have actually been rethinking how I'm designing my app as well. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Nothing code-specific, but just a general direction of how to go about it.